# Im working on a CTF project using SecGen and I have everything install and when I run the command to run SecGen this is what I get

Tags: ruby, ctf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWARs.png)

Here is a screen shot of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

`process_helper` is provided by a gem package named `process_helper`. It is very likely, that your package will contain a file `Gemfile` with a description of all the dependencies you will need - and you can install all of them using a command `bundle install`. Individually you can install packages by using eg. `gem install process_helper` for `process_helper`.

Comment: I tried running the bundle install and it did no good.  Not sure if you can see the screenshot but every time I run ruby secgen.rb run command it doesn't run a basic scenario, it just says Traceback with a list of number options.

Comment: You may want to run the app with `bundle exec ruby secgen.rb run` to ensure the correct environment being set. Also keep in mind, that if you install packages with `bundle install` on user, those won't be available on root, possibly vice versa.